How to fix ts issue in vue3 dynamic component tag
Parent.vue
<template>
    <component :is='childComponent' :childInfo="childInfo" />
</template>

<script lang='ts' setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';
import ChildA from './ChildA.vue'
import ChildB from './ChildB.vue'

const props = defineProps<{ childInfo: ChildA | ChildB }>()

const childComponent = computed(() => {
    if (props.childInfo.type === 'a') {
        return ChildA
    }

    return ChildB
})
</script>

I got a ts error like this, how to fix it?
https://i.sstatic.net/4AhIjtLj.png
Check more detail in the provided URL:
Vue Playground
I want no ts error in the component tag

Please share more details, like the error message in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem
